# ContourPlot with two parameters

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a contour diagram of a function:

```
ContourPlot[1/Sin[q \[Phi]], {q, 30, 100}, {q*\[Phi], Pi/300, Pi/200}]
```

such that in the x-axis is plotted q, whereas in the y-axis is plotted q*[Phi].

However, it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that what you want to achieve makes sense? How can the a value on the y-axis depend on the x position?

Comment: This is what I want

Comment: Is phi a fixed parameter or a variable?

Comment: phi is a variable

Comment: Then I think it can't be done, and that it also doesn't make sense to plot such a thing. Let's say phi is Pi/250 for example: what value would you expect on the y axis? it would depend on the x axis (as it represents q), hence you wouldn't be able to define a unique value for each point on y...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to abandon `ContourPlot`, unless you want to transform the plot, which is possible. Here's one approach to get the contour lines using `MeshFunctions`:

```
ParametricPlot[{q, q*\[Phi]}, {q, 30, 100}, {\[Phi], Pi/300, Pi/200},
 PlotPoints -> {500, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{q, \[Phi]}, ArcTan[1/Sin[q*\[Phi]]]]}, 
 Mesh -> 15, 
 MeshShading -> 
  ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"] /@ Subdivide[0., 1., 14], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The range on `1/Sin[q * \[Phi]]` is infinite, which causes problems. `ContourPlot` would clip the range.  Above I used `ArcTan` to tame it, because it's easier than clipping it and does not deform the contour lines.

*Addendum*

This will put phi coords & (two) grid lines on the frame:

```
pr1 = 25; pr2 = 105;
ParametricPlot[{q, q*\[Phi]}, {q, 30, 100}, {\[Phi], Pi/300, Pi/200},
 PlotPoints -> {500, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{q, \[Phi]}, ArcTan[1/Sin[q*\[Phi]]]]}, 
 Mesh -> 15, 
 MeshShading -> 
  ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"] /@ Subdivide[0., 1., 14],
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{pr1, pr2}, Automatic},
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{pr1 # &, #/pr1 &}], 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{pr2 # &, #/pr2 &}]},
   {Automatic, Automatic}},
 Prolog -> {LightGray, 
   Line[{{pr1 {1, Pi/300}, pr2 {1, Pi/300}}, {pr1 {1, Pi/200}, 
      pr2 {1, Pi/200}}}]}]
```